# Is there an opportunity to generate specific Unicode symbol randomly in Java?

Tags: java, random, unicode, ascii

I need to generate card suits appending with the number of the card (1-12) and I can't use arrays. In addition, should it be Unicode only, or it also can be ASCII symbol?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no ASCII symbol that represents a card suit.

Comment: So how can I print out these symbols? I will appreciate your help so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int index = 9824; index <= 9831; index++) {
        System.out.print("" + (char) index);
    }
}
```

You will get this output:

```
♠♡♢♣♤♥♦♧
```

I'm guessing that these are the characters that you need.

So a method like this:

```
public static int getRandomSuit() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 9824);
}
```

Will return a random suit.

Answer (score 2):

You could just generate a number ranged between your 'symbols' on an ascii chart, and then convert it to that character.

For example if

```
97=a,
98=b,
99=c,
100=d
```

You could get a random number from 97-100 and convert it to a character.

Comment: But if these symbols don't belong to specific range, like in you example (97-100), and they have numbers like, for example, 2, 47, 24 and 198? And I may sound stupid, but for this symbol -  ♥, I found only U+2665 code. And it prints ("?") all the time. Or in that case I need use only number (2665), without "U+"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well if you could use an array I'd tell you to just put those 4 numbers in an array, and then have the random number generator spit out a random index in the array, and then take that as the suit. The answer posted below mine might be more what you're looking for though, as it does what I described but he also bothered to look up the symbols : )